# "I have her for homeroom", "i have her for math "?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a question about the meaning of "for" in this sentence.

The two sentences were extracted from the book "WONDER"

"I have her for homeroom" 
"I have her for math"
She started writing the list of names on the second-to-last page of her note book.

I think that "her"=she is in the same class.

What exactly does "FOR" mean in the sentence? and Could you make another example for more explanation?

Answer (score 1):

This is a set phrase. In your example, the pronoun *her* refers to a teacher. The sentence

> I have *X* for *Y*.

means

> *X* teaches me *Y*.

where *X* is a teacher's name, and *Y* is a subject.

So:

> I have Mrs Carbuncle for Maths.

means

> Mrs Carbuncle teaches me Maths.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you kind explanation. I took it fully. She was a teacher.

Comment: I do agree with, for instance, Mick’s Answer. Further, please ask your own teacher why you’re comparing *I have her for homeroom/math/anything* to *She started writing (anything) on/in her note book*

What do you think they have in common, please?